# IIS 7 Redirect optimization for CanonicalHostNameRule combined with RemoveTrailingSlashRule1

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I have to following two rules in my IIS configuration (according to scottgu):

```
<rule name="RemoveTrailingSlashRule1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)/$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>

<rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^dev\.testing\.ch$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.testing.ch/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The CanonicalHostNameRule1 forwards all http://testing.ch to http://www.testing.ch/

And the second rule removes the backspace /

Better would be if I could forward empty testing.ch requests to www.testing.ch (without the backspace). But if I just remove it like this it obviously doesn't work:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="http://dev.testing.ch{R:1}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your rules. There is no need to combine them as requests for http://www.testing.ch/ are not caught by the first rule. This is because the first `/` after the domain name is not part of the URL that is matched against the regular expression.

PS: Assuming these rules are from your dev site (dev.testing.ch) and not the actual website.

Comment: I don't wanna combine them, but I want the second one to point to dev.testing.ch and not dev.testing.ch/

Comment: The trailing slash after the domain name is an essential part of the URL. Even if you don't include it in your redirect (or if the user types the URL), the browser will add it nonetheless. This is because the HTTP request for the homepage of `dev.testing.ch` is `GET /`.